# Спрятать окно консоли при запуске приложения Qt под Windows

Tags: windows, qt5, mingw-w64

Собрал приложение под Windows 7 на MinGW 8.10 x64

При запуске отображается окно консоли
[image: снимок экрана]

Вопрос 1: почему?

Вопрос 2: как избавиться?

Answer (score 1):

откройте .pro файл
и добавьте

```
QT -= console
```

или уберите console из

```
QT += core gui .....
```

Comment: я, до этого, под Linux всегда работал... Попросили собрать под винду. Собрал - и на тебе! Спасибо! Попробую

Comment: не помогло. Помогло лишь отключение библиотеки testlib

Comment: попробуйте еще CONFIG -=console

Comment: Пробовал - результат нулевой

Answer (score 0):

Для удаления окна терминала необходимо отключить (если она есть в конфигурации) библиотеку testlib